# Classify The Differential Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked to state if the following ordinary differential equation is linear homogeneous, linear non-homogeneous, or nonlinear then state the order with respect to the specified unknown function $k(a)$, given that $B$ is a constant and $g(a)$ is a function:

$$Bk'''-3k''+3k'-k=g(a)+a$$

I have stated that it's linear, $3$rd order, and non-homogeneous. However, I was given as wrong answer that it's not a third order non-homogenous ODE. Can anyone know why and what it is? I don't have the chance to ask the professor now. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why your answer is wrong, unless it wants you to discuss whether $B=0$, or $B$ is a function of $k$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I forgot to mention that $B$ is a constant and $g(a)$ is a function so I edited the question. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Then you will only have to say that if $B=0$, it is of order 2, otherwise it is of order $3$. It looks obviously linear and nonhomogeneous to me. Oh, one more thing, if $g(a)=-a$, then it is homonegeous.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! By the way, see here for how to input math formulas on MSE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.